# NSString to NSDate conversion for a specific format

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, nsdate

I receive NSString(s) in the following format:

```
2013-05-18T17:37:06.9419518Z
```

How do I convert the date into a NSDate properly so I can compare it with another NSDate that contains the current date/time

This is what I have right now:

```
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSZ"];

        NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
        dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:extractString];

        NSLog (@"dateFromString: %@", dateFromString);

        [dateFormatter release];
        [dateFromString release];
```

but I get a (null) output in the log out of it

thank you.

Comment: If the 'Z' is a constant at the end of your time, then you need to put it in single quotes in the date format. `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z'"];`

Comment: @DanF I'd promote that to an actual answer if I were you; it solves the problem posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 'Z' is a constant at the end of your time, then you need to put it in single quotes in the date format.

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS'Z'"];
```

Comment: No problem, I've had plenty of missteps with date formatters myself, and wasn't entirely sure when I posted the comment that it would be the actual solution